# Matrix indexing in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I was growing confused during the development of a small Python script involving matrix operations, so I fired up a shell to play around with a toy example and develop a better understanding of matrix indexing in Numpy.

This is what I did:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.matrix([1,2,3])
>>> A
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> A[0]
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> A[0][0]
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> A[0][0][0]
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> A[0][0][0][0]
matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
```

As you can imagine, this has *not* helped me develop a better understanding of matrix indexing in Numpy. This behavior would make sense for something that I would describe as "An array of itself", but I doubt anyone in their right mind would choose that as a model for matrices in a scientific library.

What is, then, the logic to the output I obtained? Why would the first element of a matrix object be itself?

PS: I know how to obtain the first entry of the matrix. What I am interested in is the logic behind this design decision.

EDIT: I'm not asking how to access a matrix element, or why a matrix row behaves like a matrix. I'm asking for a definition of the behavior of a matrix when indexed with a single number. It's an action typical of arrays, but the resulting behavior is nothing like the one you would expect from an array. I would like to know how this is implemented and what's the logic behind the design decision.

Comment: Syntax is A[dim1, dim2, ...]. For this case, to get the first element, you would do A[0,0], second element as A[0,1] and third element as A[0,2]. This is a 1 x 3 matrix.

Comment: Did anyone actually read the PS?

Comment: The `matrix` class is hard-coded to always have two dimensions (i.e. rows and columns).  This is preserved by slicing and indexing operations (unless you access a single element, e.g. `A[0, 0]`).  By the way, for most uses, the `ndarray` class (i.e. the standard numpy array) is preferred;  search for `numpy array vs matrix` to find lots of discussion about this topic.

Comment: when I first needed to do matrix maths in numpy all the help I could find directed me to use ndarray. It's much more flexible and for each of the things I tested it was faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the shape after indexing:

```
In [295]: A=np.matrix([1,2,3])
In [296]: A.shape
Out[296]: (1, 3)
In [297]: A[0]
Out[297]: matrix([[1, 2, 3]])
In [298]: A[0].shape
Out[298]: (1, 3)
```

The key to this behavior is that `np.matrix` is always 2d.  So even if you select one row (`A[0,:]`), the result is still 2d, shape `(1,3)`.  So you can string along as many `[0]` as you like, and nothing new happens.

What are you trying to accomplish with `A[0][0]`?  The same as `A[0,0]`?
For the base `np.ndarray` class these are equivalent.

Note that `Python` interpreter translates indexing to `__getitem__` calls.

```
 A.__getitem__(0).__getitem__(0)
 A.__getitem__((0,0))
```

`[0][0]` is 2 indexing operations, not one.  So the effect of the second `[0]` depends on what the first produces.

For an array `A[0,0]` is equivalent to `A[0,:][0]`.  But for a matrix, you need to do:

```
In [299]: A[0,:][:,0]
Out[299]: matrix([[1]])  # still 2d
```

=============================

> "An array of itself", but I doubt anyone in their right mind would choose that as a model for matrices in a scientific library.
>
> What is, then, the logic to the output I obtained? Why would the first element of a matrix object be itself?
>
> In addition, A[0,:] is not the same as A[0]

In light of these comments let me suggest some clarifications.

`A[0]` does not mean 'return the 1st element'.  It means select along the 1st axis. For a 1d array that means the 1st item.  For a 2d array it means the 1st row.  For `ndarray` that would be a 1d array, but for a `matrix` it is another `matrix`.  So for a 2d array or matrix, `A[i,:]` is the same thing as `A[i]`.

`A[0]` does not just return itself.  It returns a new matrix.  Different `id`:

```
In [303]: id(A)
Out[303]: 2994367932
In [304]: id(A[0])
Out[304]: 2994532108
```

It may have the same data, shape and strides, but it's a new object.  It's just as unique as the `ith` row of a many row matrix.

Most of the unique `matrix` activity is defined in: `numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py`.  I was going to suggest looking at the `matrix.__getitem__` method, but most of the action is performed in `np.ndarray.__getitem__`.

`np.matrix` class was added to `numpy` as a convenience for old-school MATLAB programmers.  `numpy` arrays can have almost any number of dimensions, 0, 1, ....  MATLAB allowed only 2, though a release around 2000 generalized it to 2 or more.

Comment: I don't see how that behavior is a consequence of a matrix always being 2d. In addition, A[0,:] is not the same as A[0] (even though they produce the same result in this case), so the fact that a matrix row is a matrix in the eyes of numpy does not explain the behavior I posted. It's interesting, however, that indexing translates to __getitem__. Seeing the implementation would perhaps shed some light on this. What I don't get is why implement array actions in a class if its behavior is not going to be that of an array. Indexing an array usually returns something other than the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have the following

```
>> A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]])
```

If you want to get the second column value, use the following:

```
>> A.T[1]
array([ 2,  6, 10])
```