# Newton method in python for multivariables (system of equations)

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.x

My code is running fine for first iteration but after that it outputs the following error:

```
ValueError: matrix must be 2-dimensional
```

To the best of my knowledge (which is not much in python), my code is correct. but I don't know, why it is not running correctly for all given iterations. Could anyone help me in this problem.

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import sympy as sp
from numpy.linalg import inv

#initial guesses
x = -2
y = -2.5
i1 = 0

while i1<5:
    F= np.matrix([[(x**2)+(x*y**3)-9],[(3*y*x**2)-(y**3)-4]])
    theta = np.sum(F)
    J = np.matrix([[(2*x)+y**3, 3*x*y**2],[6*x*y, (3*x**2)-(3*y**2)]])
    Jinv = inv(J) 
    xn = np.array([[x],[y]])    
    xn_1 = xn - (Jinv*F)
    x = xn_1[0]
    y = xn_1[1]
    #~ print theta
    print xn
    i1 = i1+1
```

Comment: `x = xn_1[0]; y = xn_1[1]` takes the *first and second rows* of your numpy arrays. This means that on your second iteration, `[[(x**2)+(x*y**3)-9],[(3*y*x**2)-(y**3)-4]]`  will result in a value with more than 2 dimensions, which may or may not be what you want, but in any event, `np.matrix` objects *have* to be 2 dimensional. What values *should* `x` and `y` take? Also note, you should generally avoid `np.matrix`, which is pretty much deprecated anyway... But you *definitely* probably shouldn't be mixing the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `xn_1` is a 2D matrix. Try printing it you and you will see `[[something], [something]]`

Therefore to get the x and y, you need to use multidimensional indexing. Here is what I did

```
x = xn_1[0,0]
y = xn_1[1,0]
```

This works because within the 2D matrix `xn_1` are two single element arrays. Therefore we need to further index 0 to get that single element.

Edit: To clarify, `xn_1[1,0]` means to index 1 and then take that subarray and index 0 on that. [And although according to Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#single-element-indexing) it may seem that it should be functionally equivalent to `xn_1[1][0]`, **that only applies to the general `np.array` type and not the `np.matrix` type**. [Here is an excellent thread on SO that explains this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026505/matrix-indexing-in-numpy).

So you should use the `xn_1[1,0]` way to get the element you want.

Answer (score 1):

`xn_1` is a numpy matrix, so it's elements are accessed with the `item()` method, not like an array. (with `[]`s)

So just change

```
x = xn_1[0]
y = xn_1[1]
```

to

```
x = xn_1.item(0)
y = xn_1.item(1)
```

Comment: Huh? Element access works the same for both `numpy.ndarray` objects and `np.matrix` objects.

Comment: `xn_1[0]` returns another `np.matrix` object. I'm not sure why, but it seems using indices on a matrix object only returns other `np.matrix` objects. To get the actual number, you have to use `item()`. `xn_1[0][0]` returns the same thing as `xn_1[0]`.

Comment: Yes, but `some_array` with the same shape as `xn_1` would *also return a non-scaler object*. `np.matrix` objects will always be forced to have 2-dimensions, though. So there is a discrepancy there. But fundamentally, you want `xn_1[0, 0]` and not rely on chained-indexing (which you should avoid with `numpy.ndarrays` as well, for various resons)